# floor(a/(double)b)*b==a if a%b==0 in C?

Tags: c, floating-point

Wondering if below assertion is correct if a and b are both integers > 0. Can float number precision cause problem in this condition?

```
assert(a%b || floor(a/(double)b)*b==a);
```

Comment: Your assertion fails for any `a` which is not a multiple of `b`

Comment: In the (typical) case of 32-bit int and 64-bit double, this should be fine.  (If you were using float rather than double, you wouldn't be able to represent all values.)

Comment: Why are you checking for the same condition twice(as `float(a/b)*b==a` will give the same boolean value as `a%b==0`)?

Comment: @MaheshBansod: that's the point of the question.

Comment: You can try std::cout << (4.31 * 10000 != 43100) << '\n';

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thank you for pointing that out but the question has been editted now.
 The `assert` will always be correct as `a%b` will be true if no.s are not divisible and `floor(a/(double)b)*b==a` will be true if no.s are divisible. The `||` operator will evaluate the whole statement to be true if anyone condition is true.

Comment: @ZhouHuabing: how does that relate to the question?

Comment: @ZhouHuabing It was true, how?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, I just wanna show MaheshBansod float precision may affect my assertion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the first part of the condition is false, then `a` is a multiple of `b`.

The conversion to `double` of an integer is generally exact (if `double` is IEEE 754's binary64, it is exact for integers up to 2<sup>53</sup>). Assuming these conditions, `a/(double)b` is the `double` nearest to the real division of `a` by `b`. Since the real result is an integer below 2<sup>53</sup>, it is exactly representable, so no rounding occurs (in other words the floating-point division is exact).

`floor()` applied to a `double` that represents an integer returns the same integer.

The floating-point multiplication is exact for the same reasons as the division, and produces exactly `a`.

Conclusion: the condition in the `assert` is always true, for `a` and `b` between -2<sup>53</sup> and 2<sup>53</sup>, for a platform that implements `double` as binary64, with or without excess precision.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't correct for 64 bit integers. The right side needs to be correct for a, b where a is an integer multiple of b. If a, b <= 2^53, then both can be converted to double without rounding error, a / (double) b will calculate the exact result, and everything will be fine.

But if a > 2^53, then converting a to double may round the result down. Then a / (double) b may be a tiny bit smaller than the exact result, floor () will round it down, and the result will be wrong. An example where the assertion will fail is

```
long long a = (1LL << 53) + 1;
long long b = a / 3;
```

If you used float, then

assert(a%b || floor(a/(float)b)*b==a);

would fail for much smaller values.